# DB Normalization and single field break outs

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, normalization, database-normalization

My question has probably been asked many times, but I can't quite find it (nor has googling been very good).

I'm trying to normalize our DB. Here is the example:

Say we currently have a single table:

```
Property
---------
id
name
type
```

types can either be:

multi-family
single-family
healthcare
commercial

I could break this into a separate table so that we have:

```
Property       Prop_Type
--------       ----------
id             prop_id
name           type
type_id
```

According to 2-n, I should break this up. But what am I actually saving in performance? I agree that breaking up tables like this makes it easier for us to insert new types of real estate, or modify current ones. But assuming that this isn't very necessary, would this result in a performance increase? The field Property.type is holding up to a 32 byte string versus a Property.type_id which is similar (no?). Plus there is an additional table required in the second option, and a join every time we want to access that data. Finally, our DB is not that large (maybe tens of thousands of records), so space saving is not a priority.

Should I continue to normalize or should I hold off on these small individual breaks?

Thank you!

Comment: The more important reason to normalize is logic and consistency.  Also the foreign key field will normally be 32 *bits* rather than 32 bytes.  You might even make it a 1- or 2-byte field since you probably won't need more rows in the lookup table.  For tens of thousands of records, you probably won't notice a difference in performance, but the normalized version will probably have better performance because there will be fewer cache misses and less paging.

Comment: Can you explain the logic and consistency part? As in, it takes away the potential to mistype something, such as commercial vs comercial? What is the logic part?

Comment: Logic: you want to have a well defined set of values.  A lookup represents that logically; a free entry text field does not.  It may not seem significant now, with small numbers of tables and rows, but as the application grows you'll want it normalized.  Better to start now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with normalization.  The functional dependencies in both examples are equivalent - id determines name and type.  However, in the first example you're using the same values for identification and description.  The question here is whether you simply need labels for types, or do you need a stable, compact identifier?

Comment: @phoog ZAR's proposed change has nothing to do with normalization. Also, there is no difference in what is represented between ids and no ids with a text field or any other kind since any values that you can enter in one you also can enter in the other. Although ergonomically a separate name table is less likely to hold unintended names because then updating Property doesn't also update the names in use.

Comment: @philipxy please explain your puzzling assertion that theproposed change has nothing to do with normalization.  Also, why do you say there is no difference and then go on to describe one of the differences, indeed, the very difference that causes the lookup table to be a better logical model for the business domain?

Comment: @phoog 1. See my answer below. 2. I said that there is no difference in what is represented, ie the business situation. (Ignoring the particuar id values, which are arbitrary, and are not part of the (original) business domain.) Then I said that there is a difference in the likelihood of errors in that one can update less at a time and so get less wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I continue to normalize or should I hold off on these small individual breaks?

Normalization to higher normal forms replaces a table by others using the same columns that join back to the original based on functional dependencies and join dependencies.

> According to 2-n, I should break this up

Presumably you mean 2NF. You have not given any information to justify that. And what you discuss doing has nothing to do with normalization.

Looks like you undertand litte about normalization. Get a reference presenting and explaining its issues, definitions and procedures. Use them. Quote them.

> But what am I actually saving in performance?

Normalization should be done regardless of performance. You change when justified by the demonstrated present value of changing to another particular design based on the ideal/original.

It's not meaningful to talk about a design's performance without having been given details for a particular DBMS implementation plus expected use. But roughly speaking introducing ids uses less space but causes more joins.

DBMSes *exist* to have information stored in tables queried by algebra and/or conditions as implemented by the DBMS. Just make the most straightforard design. You need to understand way more about schemas and querying before you will know enough to modify a design for performance.

> I agree that breaking up tables like this makes it easier for us to insert new types of real estate,

No, it makes it harder. All you used to have to do is enter the type value you wanted in a Property row. With ids you have to add a Prop_Type row and use that type_id in a Property row.

If possible values for Property type are fixed then add a CHECK constraint on Property type:

```
CHECK(type IN ('multi-family','single-family','healthcare','commercial'))
```

(Otherwise, don't.)

If you want possible values for properties to be updated and queried without a schema change and there does not have to be a property for every type then that is something that your original design cannot express. But you still don't need to introduce ids; you can have a Prop_Type table with just a type column and a foreign key from Property type to Prop_Type type.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not a normalization problem.

The type column is essentially a discrete type, i.e. has a finite set of values - currently multi-family, single-family, healthcare, commercial.

What you want is to control that no invalid value is inserted into the column. Your prop_type table and a foreign key constraint is one solution.

A more suitable solution is to use a CHECK CONSTRAINT on the column:

```
CREATE TABLE Property
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name ...,
    type varchar(20) CONSTRAINT typeValues CHECK (type IN ('multi-family', 'single-family', 'healthcare', 'commercial'))
)
```

Going further there is no need to store the complete type string in every record. You could simply use a single character to **encode** the type:

```
CREATE TABLE Property
(
    ...
    type char(1) CONSTRAINT typeValues CHECK (type IN ('M', 'S', 'H', 'C'))
)
```

When you present the type, e.g. in a GUI, you would need to translate them into user readable text. To enter a value you would use a dropdown in the GUI.

Comment: So what is a case where I would want to break a table further down? The above is just an example, but I'm looking for a guideline as to when to break down and when not to. Thanks!

Comment: @ZAR I would use string types like these only in cases where there is a very small fixed and complete set of values which are NOT displayed to users.  Even then I'd strongly consider the alternatives.

Comment: Alternatives.. Such as? I'm not sure I follow

Comment: Changing to ids that are FKs into a table of types ensures "no invalid value is inserted into the column" in Property but there's nothing to stop an invalid (type) value to be entered into Prop_Type. Moving to higher NFs never introduces new columns, it makes more tables using the same columns. I agree that if the type values are fixed then they should be pushed into DDL. But if they are not fixed then there is no integrity benefit to adding ids.

Comment: "A more suitable solution is to use a CHECK CONSTRAINT on the column" is very debatable, especially as you go on to suggest that a single character code would be better, and that the translation of those would then be held in the application. You're describing an application-layer foreign key, and at some point a developer will find that the meanings of those codes are not available in the database and will duplicate the logic there, possibly by creating just the kind of lookup table that this design is trying to avoid.